# Can you have a PHP $_POST variable that is set to an array?

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, jquery, post

I am using AJAX to put some data in my database. I am using JSON to submit the data to a PHP page. I am using a POST request. Can you set one of the POST variables as an array? Below I have the full AJAX request, but here is the part where I am setting two parts of the data as arrays:

```
"content[]" : testContentArray,
"content_attr[]" : testContentAttributes,
```

Below is my full AJAX (using jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../includes/create_test_main.ajax.php",
                data:   {"tags" : $('#testTags').val(),
                                         "title" : $('#testTitle').val(),
                                         "subject" : $('#testSubject').val(),
                                         "description" : $('#testDescription').val(),
                                         "content[]" : testContentArray,
                                         "content_attr[]" : testContentAttributes,
                                         "user_id" : user_id},
                success: 

                                     function(testId) {//redirect Page
                                        window.location.href = "http://localhost/nvr_forget/public_html/test/" + testId + "/";
                                     }
            });
        };
```

If that is the way to do it, how would I handle it on the PHP side? do I handle the $_POST variable as a normal array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass an array within a `data` object to `$.ajax`, it is parsed out into `name[]=value` format.  This is done using [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param), so I'll illustrate using that:

```
jQuery.param({'foo': [1, 2, 5]})
// "foo%5B%5D=1&foo%5B%5D=2&foo%5B%5D=5"
```

`%5B` and `%5D` are uri-encoded square brackets.  This is a common way of sending multiple values for the same key to a server.  PHP parses it into an array, so in this case:

```
var_export($_POST['foo']);
// array ('1', '2', '5')
```

So in your code, `$_POST['content']` and `$_POST['content_attr']` should both be arrays.  The square brackets that you've used are unnecessary, but won't break anything.

[See the PHP manual on the subject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).

Comment: So how would you loop through those arrays? something like `while($_POST['content']) { /*do something*/ }`?

Comment: @chromedude You can't use `while` to loop through an array (well, you can, but it would be silly in almost every conceivable circumstance). Use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: jQuery.param basically accomplishes my solution, but like I said, you're just using another serializer .. which is fine I guess if you're just mucking about :P

Comment: ok, great! so what I have there (minus the brackets) and assuming that `testContentArray` and `testContentAttributes` are arrays will work?

Comment: jQuery does have a special 'json' option you can pass in .ajax/.post functions. You might as well use that.

Comment: @chromedude Don't strangle my pet hamster if it doesn't, but I would expect them to, yes.

Comment: @lonesomeday, ok I will try not to :)

Comment: +1 Why do all the other people want to stringify it or say this can not be done?

Comment: @lonesomeday looks like I don't have to strangle your hamster :). Thanks so much... it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can - it can be either simple array (with integers as keys) or associative array. It just depends what JSON object you submit.

For example if you submit the following JSON object:

```
var data = {
    'a': 'test123',
    'b': [
        'x',
        'y',
        'z'
    ],
    'c': {
        'testing': 'abc',
        'blah': 'qwerty'
    }
}
```

You will have the following elements within `$_POST`:

- `$_POST['a']` - containing string `test123`,
- `$_POST['b']` - containing array (`array('x','y','z')`),
- `$_POST['c']` - also containing array, but associative (`array('testing'=>'abc','blah'=>'qwerty')`),

Comment: I don't think this works. `$_POST['b']` will end up being `"Array"` instead of `['x','y','z']`

Comment: @Frits This is because you just echoed it. You will not echo array like that (this is common mistake among PHP beginners). Try to use `print_r($_POST['b'])` or `var_dump($_POST['b'])` instead of `echo $_POST['b']` and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Would echo produce Array with quotes around it? I think not. Please don't assume. I could have typed "`string (5) "Array"`" but that's just silly now isn't it?

Comment: @Frits My answer is not based on so called 'assumption', but on so called 'experience'. If you _really_ want to output `['x','y','z']` and you pass the data from JS correctly (=as I described), you can do `echo "['".implode("','",$_POST['b'])."']";`. But I would not be surprised if you would get something else - just give me more details and let me solve the issue for you.

Comment: That's a partial solution. If `$_POST['b']` were an empty array it would print `['']` regardless (which is an array with one element: an empty string). This is going far off topic, but just to avoid confusion ;) - Just use var_dump kids

Comment: @Frits I know it is offtopic, but if you want it, just add condition ;) `echo count($_POST['b'])?"['".implode("','",$_POST['b'])."']":'[]';`. Is it ok now? This is only to display it in a way you wanted (I do not know the purpose, however).

Answer (score 0):

You can post an object from JS (JSON) and json_decode it on server (PHP) with json_decode.

Comment: This is completely not needed. OP has JSON on JS side and if he uses jQuery's `.post()` function, he sends the data that is then treated as array by PHP. Why do you need to construct string from the JS object and then decode it?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it, but you have to do it fully manually like so:

```
{
    "content[0]": "a",
    "content[1]": "b",
    "content[2]": "c",
    "content[multi][0]": "d"
}
```

`$_POST['content']` will then look like:

```
Array(
    0 => "a",
    1 => "b",
    2 => "c",
    multi => Array(
        0 => "d"
    )
)
```

It would be a lot simpler to just:

```
{
    "blob" : JSON.stringify(data_or_array_or_whatever)
}
```

In PHP you can then retrieve it by:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['blob'], true);
```

This needs the json2.js library for older browsers though.

I'd go for the latter as in the former you're likely to be writing your own serializer in the end :P - which is exactly why we have JSON.

Comment: @Frits Using jQuery and assigning array to one of the properties of JSON object (object that is then sent to the server through `.post()` method) works without the need to JSON stringify (on client side) & decoding (on PHP side), so no additional library is required.

Comment: Then why is OP having problems with it? Regardless, my point stands if you'd want to do this without using jQuery.

Comment: @Frits Because he is a beginner. But he asks more experienced people and he expects there is someone out there who knows how to send data through AJAX using jQuery. But you may be right if you are trying to do it without jQuery - I have looked at your answer in context of the question. However, you are saying that he needs json2.js instead - for him it may not be useful or even reasonable (he uses jQuery), but I will revoke my downvote as soon as I can (it is now locked).

Comment: You should be able to revoke the down-vote. Thank you. I'm assuming this question will be indexed by search machines so I always try to give the most broad and explaining answer possible. I'd rather not rely too much on the internal magic of jQuery, seeing as the question is very generic and doesn't mention jQuery (in the title). I think it helps understanding of the underlying principles.

Comment: @Frits Downvote revoked. I have a different opinion, though - he _is_ using jQuery (judging from the tags and actual content of the question) and such a practice (just assigning complicated JSON object containing also eg. arrays, and not bothering with making strings of it) is: 1) quite common (really), 2) quite easy (adds level of abstraction), 3) quite useful (shorter code, easier to read and debug), 4) quite optimized (made by jQuery makers)

Comment: I agree that it is common, easy and useful. I'm also sure it's optimized (but likely not very fast, JSON.stringify is actually a native function in newer browsers). But common, easy and useful doesn't mean: good (in this case, it might be). I think my argument still holds. jQuery isn't in the title of the question so it will get indexed as-is without the obvious mention of jQuery. I do appreciate constructive criticism, but my opinion on this is fairly solid. I do see your point but I would encourage people to look beyond jQuery and truly understand the principles.